# AngularJS: Using 2 select segments with an ng-repeat on each not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an html with 2 select segments and each are populated by ng-repeats. idea is below...

```
<select ng-model="bank" style="width: 87%; height: 28px; font-size: 15px;">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Bank Account</option>
    <option ng-repeat="bn in banks" value="$index">{{bn.nickname}}</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="case" style="width: 87%; height: 28px; font-size: 15px;">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Case Selection</option>
    <option ng-repeat="cs in cases" value="$index">{{cs.nickname}}</option>
</select>
```

this is inside a form with an ng-submit to call an add function below...

```
$scope.addPay = function (bnk, cs) {
    var a = $scope.banks[bnk].nickname;
    var b = $scope.cases[cs].nickname;
$scope.payments.push({ 
    bank: a,  
    cas: b
});
}
```

The function is inside a controller and syntactically correct.
However the submit isnt pushing the payment into the array.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is $scope.addPay this within the same controller scope as $scope.banks and $scope.cases?

Comment: Your `addPay` function has a missing end curly bracket, but I guess that's only a typo.

Comment: yep.   the button is of type="submit" and the form encompasses all of it.  the form has an ng-submit in it.  but i used something similar before, its just that i thought the 2 $index s could be messing it up

Comment: @Olariu yeah typo, sorry.   i just need to know if the idea of using the 2 ng-repeats wont mess up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not interpolating `value="$index"`, so the value of `bnk` and `cs` is `"$index"`.  Instead you likely want `value="{{ $index }}"`.  See [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/eakwcm48o7NyHZjqf9SJ?p=preview).